# main.xxxxxxxxxxxx.js in build file contains img src=x onerror=alert(1) which is related to XSS vulnerability. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Tags: angular, security, angular-cli, xss

While making a production build in Angular, the main.xxxxxxxx.js created contains the code

```
<img src="</style><img src=x onerror=alert(1)"//>
```

which we can find doing Ctrl + F. I have confirmed the behaviour in multiple projects including the boilerplate one. Since this particular line of code seems malicious due to its relation to XSS attacks, is there a way to get rid of it ? Also, can someone explain why this suspicious line exist if by any chance it serves a purpose or it is a bug on the part of Angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can someone explain why this suspicious line exist if by any chance

It looks like it's inserted as a sanitisation script, you can see it [being added here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/core/src/sanitization/inert_body.ts#L41)

```js
inertBodyElement.innerHTML = '<svg><p><style><img src="</style><img src=x onerror=alert(1)//">';
```

and this class has the description

```js
/**
 * This helper class is used to get hold of an inert tree of DOM elements containing dirty HTML
 * that needs sanitizing.
 * Depending upon browser support we must use one of three strategies for doing this.
 * Support: Safari 10.x -> XHR strategy
 * Support: Firefox -> DomParser strategy
 * Default: InertDocument strategy
 */
```

The [spec file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/core/test/sanitization/html_sanitizer_spec.ts#L210) references a [DOMPurify release](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/releases/tag/0.6.7) which seems to be related to a [Mozilla security bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1205631). The DOMPurify release notes state:

> Users who install this latest release are not affected by the bug
>   anymore as DOMPurify fixes around the problem and mitigates the issue
>   by not trusting Gecko's innerHTML implementation any much longer.
>   Instead of the combination of document.implementation and
>   doc.body.outerHTML, DOMPurify is now using the DOMParser feature
>   available in all modern browsers.

So this piece of code is **sanitising the DOM to prevent this XSS attack**. It is not an exploit in itself.

> is there a way to get rid of it?

You don't want to get rid of this, it's a good thing